# Django not showing blank validation message on one of my field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a problem with my field.

I have two field that have same field and widget. But one of the field didn't show blank validation message.

**Model:**

```py
class MagangLetter(models.Model):
    to=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    reason=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start_date=models.DateField()
    end_date=models.DateField()
```

**Form:**

```py
class MagangLetterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=MagangLetter
        fields=['to','reason','start_date','end_date']
        widgets={
            'to':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control','rows':'3','placeholder':'''#example'''}),
            'reason':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control','rows':'3','placeholder':'''#example'''}),
            'start_date':forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'date'}),
            'end_date':forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','type':'date'})
        }
```

**View**

```py
class CreateLetterMagang(CreateView):
    model=MagangLetter
    form_class=MagangLetterForm
    template_name_suffix="_create_form"
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context=super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form:MagangLetter=context['form']
        file_template=Template(services.letter.get_html_template('magang.docx'))
        date=datetime.datetime.now()
        day=settings.MONTHS[date.strftime('%m')]
        file_context=Context({
            'letter_number' : '........',
            'date_submitted' : f'{date:%d} {day} {date:%Y}',
            'to': form['to'],
            'name': self.request.user.get_full_name(),
            'nim': self.request.user.detail.id_number,
            'reason':form['reason'],
            'start_date': form['start_date'],
            'end_date': form['end_date'],
            'nip':'.............',
            'dosen':'...............',
            'sign': ''
        })
        html=file_template.render(file_context)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        date_submit=soup.find(string=re.compile("Yogyakarta,"))
        p=soup.find(string=re.compile("#test"))
        date_submit.parent.parent['style']='width:15rem;'
        p.parent['class']='p-0'
        p=soup.find(string=re.compile("#test"))
        p.parent['class']='p-0'
        p=soup.find(string=re.compile("#test"))
        p.parent['class']='p-0'
        table=(p.next_element.next_element.next_element)
        table['class'].append('text-center ms-auto')
        table['style']='width:fit-content'
        date_forms=soup.find_all(type='date')
        for date_form in date_forms:
            date_form['class'].append('w-25')
            date_form['style']='min-width:fit-content;'
        context['docx']=soup.prettify()
        return context
```

**Template:**

```html
{% block body %}
<div class="row content d-block overflow-auto">
    <div class="card p-3" style="width:40rem;">
        <form method='post'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{docx|safe}}
            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Buat Surat'></input>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

[validation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlkM6.png)

`to` field not showing validation message.

`reason` field showing validation message.

How do I show this validation on both field?

Comment: This is not a Django problem, that image of the validation you do is validation done by the _browser_. Also your code is unnecessarily complicated, why do you need beautiful soup to parse HTML that you are generating, and replace values? Simply generate the HTML as you want it in the first place...

Comment: i need beautifulsoup to style html from mammoth package. My code converted docx to html.
like you said `validation done by the browser`, i just dont know why browser treat my field different from other field.
thanks for your comment and suggestion.